# Recurring job doesn't get called on set time

Tags: c#, hangfire

I have a recurring job that is called on Startup. 
It should call PlaceOrder() every 20 seconds.

Job looks like this

```
 RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<MethodCaller>(a => a.PlaceOrder(), "*/20 * * * * *");
```

PlaceOrder() method calls RevokeOrder() after 5 seconds delay.

Methods

```
    public void PlaceOrder()
    {
        DateTimeOffset d = DateTimeOffset.Now;

        Debug.WriteLine("PLACED : {0}", d);
        Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith(t => RevokeOrder());
    }

    public void RevokeOrder()
    {
        DateTimeOffset d = DateTimeOffset.Now;

        Debug.WriteLine("REVOKED : {0}",d);
    }
```

Problem is that both methods are called in every 15 seconds or sometimes in every 30 seconds instead of 20.

Logs :

```
PLACED : 1:59:27 
 REVOKED : 1:59:32 
PLACED : 1:59:42 
 REVOKED : 1:59:47 
PLACED : 2:00:12 
 REVOKED : 2:00:17 
PLACED : 2:00:27 
 REVOKED : 2:00:32 
PLACED : 2:00:43 
 REVOKED : 2:00:48
```

I want PlaceOrder() and RevokeOrder() methods to be called every 20 seconds. But there should be 5 seconds delay between them. How do I fix it?

Comment: Not sure if this will fix it but add an await InFront of Task.Delay(5000) and also set that method to async Task

Comment: @RyanGaudion did it. Problem remains the same

Comment: Please can you show the code around the recurring job. How are you setting that up?

Comment: If you mean hangfire setup code, hangfire works fine when only one method needs to be fired. When I am trying to call RevokeOrders() from PlaceOrder() that is when it gets messy? Problem with Task.Delay maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below a working Console Application that resolves the issue. Uses a timer instead of the recurringJob.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
            var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

            var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(async (e) =>
            {
                await PlaceOrderAsync();
            }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async Task PlaceOrderAsync()
        {
            DateTimeOffset d = DateTimeOffset.Now;

            Console.WriteLine("PLACED : {0}", d);
            await Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith(t => RevokeOrder());
        }

        public static void RevokeOrder()
        {
            DateTimeOffset d = DateTimeOffset.Now;

            Console.WriteLine("REVOKED : {0}", d);
        }
    }
```